# JSON function to pull the header row as first row and data range to be a single row

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have this code which converts any named range to a json string. But considers the first row of selected range as header. What I want is that the first row of my excel sheet always works as a header(fixed) and any row/rows selected as a range gets converted into a json with the headers from first fixed row

```
    ' Check there must be at least two columns in the Excel file
    If rng.Columns.Count < 2 Then
        ExcelToJSON = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim dataLoop, headerLoop As Long
    ' Get the first row of the Excel file as a header
    Dim headerRange As Range: Set headerRange = Sheet1.Range(rng.Rows(1).Address)
    ' Count the number of columns of targeted Excel file
    Dim colCount As Long: colCount = headerRange.Columns.Count
    Dim JSON As String: JSON = "["
    For dataLoop = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        ' Skip the first row of the Excel file because it is used as header
        If dataLoop > 1 Then
            ' Start data row
            Dim jsonData As String: jsonData = "{"
            ' Loop through each column and combine with the header
            For headerLoop = 1 To colCount
                jsonData = jsonData & """" & headerRange.Value2(1, headerLoop) & """" & ":"
                jsonData = jsonData & """" & rng.Value2(dataLoop, headerLoop) & """"
                jsonData = jsonData & ","
            Next headerLoop
            ' Strip out the comma in last value of each row
            jsonData = Left(jsonData, Len(jsonData) - 1)
            ' End data row
            JSON = JSON & jsonData & "},"
        End If
    Next
    ' Strip out the last comma in last row of the Excel data
    JSON = Left(JSON, Len(JSON) - 1)
    JSON = JSON & "]"
    ExcelToJSON = JSON
End Function
```

Comment: Your code runs just fine for me. What is the problem or error you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Change the assignment of the value to `headerRange`, i.e.

```
Set headerRange = Sheet1.Cells(1, rng.Column).Resize(1, rng.Columns.Count)
```

and then comment out the line below

```
If dataLoop > 1 Then
```

together with its corresponding

```
End If
```

line.

(btw your `dataLoop` variable is of `Variant` type, as you must specify the data type after *each* variable when you declare several on the same line)

Comment: Thanks. I took a different approach but i guess would be serving the same purpose.  Set my function as ````headerRange = Sheet1.Range(rng.Offset(-rng.Row + 1, 0).Address) . I guess this would do the same job right?

Comment: @ABCoder, no, that's not the same, as your code results in `headerRange` having as many rows as the original range - try it when you pass in a multi-row range... (it's also less efficient, when you know in advance that you want to start in the first row of the worksheet, i.e. avoidable calls to `Offset` and `Row`)